# Jags: Attempt to redefine node error, mixed effect regression

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, bugs

I want to perform a mixed effect regression in `rjags`, with a random slope and intercept. I define the following toy dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

global_slope <- 1
global_int <- 1

Npoints_per_group <- 50
N_groups <- 10
pentes <- rnorm(N_groups,-1,.5)

centers_x <- seq(0,10,length = N_groups)
center_y <- global_slope*centers_x + global_int

group_spread <- 2
group_names <- sample(LETTERS,N_groups)

df <- lapply(1:N_groups,function(i){
  x <- seq(centers_x[i]-group_spread/2,centers_x[i]+group_spread/2,length = Npoints_per_group)
  y <- pentes[i]*(x- centers_x[i])+center_y[i]+rnorm(Npoints_per_group)
  data.table(x = x,y = y,ID = group_names[i])
}) %>% rbindlist()

ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color = as.factor(ID)))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

This is a typical situation of Simpson paradox: an overall increasing trend when you have a decreasing trend within each group (given by the `ID` variable).

I define the following model:

```
library(rjags)

model_code_simpson <- 
" model
{

 # first level
  for (i in 1:n) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm(alpha[i] + beta[i] * x[i], tau)
    alpha[i] = alpha[group[i]] # random intercept
    beta[i] = beta[group[i]] # random slope
  }

# second level
for(j in 1:J){
alpha[j] ~ dnorm(mu.alpha, tau.alpha)
beta[j] ~ dnorm(mu.beta, tau.beta)
}

# Priors
mu.alpha ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
mu.beta ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
sigma ~ dunif(0,10)
sigma.alpha ~ dunif(0,10)
sigma.beta ~ dunif(0,10)

# Derived quantities
tau <- pow(sigma,-2)
tau.alpha <- pow(sigma.alpha,-2)
tau.beta <- pow(sigma.beta,-2)

}
"

# Choose the parameters to watch
model_parameters <- c("mu.alpha","tau.alpha","tau.beta","tau")

# define numeric grouping variable
df[,ID2 := .GRP,by = ID]

model_data <- list(n = nrow(df), 
                   y = df$y, 
               x = df$x,
                   group = df$ID2,
                   J = df[,uniqueN(ID)])

model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_code_simpson),
                    data = model_data,
                    n.chains = 2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
Deleting model

Error in jags.model(textConnection(model_code_simpson), data = model_data,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 8.
Attempt to redefine node beta[1]
```

I do not understand what is happening, and related questions did not help me much.

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with jags syntax but your first for loop doesn't make any sense to me. I'm guessing it should be something like this:

```
y[i] ~ dnorm(alpha[group[i]]+ beta[group[i]] * x[i], tau)
```

or if you want to be more verbose something like

```
individual_alpha[i] = alpha[group[i]]
individual_beta[i] = beta[group[i]]
y[i] ~ dnorm(individual_alpha[i]+ individual_beta[i] * x[i], tau)
```

Note that your variables `alpha` and `beta` are random variables of size `N_groups`, eg $\alpha_j, \beta_j$ for $j = 1,\ldots,m$ so you cannot index them using the same index as your observations eg like the $i$ in $y_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.